# Google Sheet Script - Find Value in Col and Delete Row

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

So I'm working on a script to search my Google Sheet for a value and then delete the row, so far I have this:

```
function sort() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 
  var rowsDeleted = 0; 

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) { 
    var row = values[i]; 
    if (row[0] == 'test') { 
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted); rowsDeleted++; 
    } 
  } 
};
```

So what I got so far is that I can exact match the text, but I want to find all cols which contains "test" and not only "test". So it will delete rows with data like:

1. This is a test
2. Test me again
3. ThisTestIsNotWorking

Any solution :)?

Comment: try `if (row[0].indexOf('test') > -1)` instead

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: I added it as an answer, if you can accept it it's easier for others with the same problem as you to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:
`if (row[0].indexOf('test') > -1)`

The problem with your solution was that it only checked if the row was exactly equal to `test`, this instead checks if the row contains `test` at all.