# getRange('A1:B') keeps going for ages - part of delete rows when cell does not contain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[My sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y0uhmMgKVjQuPDxKCKbsWJ3TIe2rNn8pcaMOAexTUgY/edit?usp=sharing)

I have 2 columns, A contains units & B data. I want to delete entire rows from A & B where text in B does not contain '-'.

I have other data in the other columns in the sheet, so this should only apply to A & B.

I normally manually filter and delete these rows.

Following the script in this question, when I used exactly this but with "| My Text Here" replace with "-", it worked, but a lot of the data that should be there were also deleted. So when I should have had 300 rows of data left, I only had 124 after running the script.
[How to delete rows that do not containing specific text within A column using Google Sheets App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644355/how-to-delete-rows-that-do-not-containing-specific-text-within-a-column-using-go)

```
function deleteFunction(){
  //declarations
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  for(var i=values.length-1;i>0;i--){
    var myValue=values[i][0];
          Logger.log(i);
    if( myValue.indexOf("-")==-1){
      Logger.log(myValue);
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

When I change the dataRange to just `getRange('A1:B');` the function keeps going for ages without results.

I changed it to `.getRange(1, 2, dataRange.getLastRow(), dataRange.getLastColumn());` and that deletes ALL the data in the range.

Basically, at this point I'm confused, I keep changing the ranges to try to see results.

I'm a newbie to this so I'm not sure where I go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try it this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shsr = 3;//data startrow atleast in your sample
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getRange(shsr, 1 , sh.getLastRow() - shsr + 1, 2);
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!~r[1].toString().indexOf('-')) {
      sh.deleteRow(i + shsr - d++)
    }
  });
}
```

You need to count the number of rows that you delete because all of the row move up as you delete them. So you have to keep subtracting a larger offset as you delete more and more lines because indexing of the array does not change.  Also you were using values[i][0] which is column one and your data indicate it should have been column 2. And finally by using sh.getDataRange() you start running your code at line one instead of line 3 where your data starts.

#### or this way

This method is a little quicker because you are not deleting one row at a time.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shsr = 3;
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getRange(shsr, 1 , sh.getLastRow() - shsr + 1, 2);
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  let d = 0;
  let o = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (~r[1].toString().indexOf('-')) {
      o.push(r)
    }
  });
  rg.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(shsr, 1, o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

In the latter case we are keeping load the rows that we want into an output array and then removing all lines from the shsr to the bottom and replacing them with the wanted lines.

Comment: This works perfectly. Frankly, I thought that it was only a matter of just putting in the range, your code is a whole brand new one. I hope you can help me understand how I can change the range, e.g. if I want col. E & F. I tried `sh.getRange(shsr, 5 , sh.getLastRow() - shsr + 1, 6);` but didn't work, it removed everything.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The current situation is that if column B contains a - then that's a row that you wish to keep and you wish to eliminate all others.  So what do you mean by the statement `If I want columns E and F.

Comment: I also wanted to know how to change the range, since I was struggling with that and how you have use getRange() I haven't seen that code anywhere. But thanks so much for your code @Cooper. You've gotten me this far, I'll figure out how to change the range :)

Comment: shsr isi the row where data starts and sh.getLastRow() - shsr + 1 is that number of rows in that range.